# Where condition for Wp_posts in WP_QUERY

Tags: wordpress

I am getting problem to fetch records with WP_QUERY in wordpress. I have a working custom Query but I need this query in the form of WP_QUERY.

```
Select * from wp_posts where post_type = 'awards' AND post_status = 'publish' AND ID < '$lastmsg' order by ID desc limit 4;
```

My Arguments for WP_QUERY

```
$args = array(
   'post_type' => 'awards',
   'post_status' => 'publish',
   'posts_per_page' => 4,
   'meta_query' => array(
          array( 
              'key' => 'ID',
              'value' => $POST_ID,
              'compare' => '<'
          )
    )
);
```

Please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: can you please share what  error you get?

Comment: In first query you are fetching data from wp_posts only but in second query you are fetching data from two table by using of meta_query. Here is the example I hope it will helpfull for you.http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/167848/select-from-wpdb-posts-where-id-160()

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I know my Second Query is wrong. And  I just want to convert first one custom Query in the form of WP_QUERY like 2nd one query but I don't know how to implement where condition for wp_posts table.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the alternative solution for your problem. I hope it will work for you.

```
<?php
$fivesdrafts = $wpdb->get_results( 
    "
    SELECT * 
    FROM $wpdb->posts
    WHERE post_status = 'draft' 
        AND post_author = 5
    "
);

if ( $fivesdrafts )
{
    foreach ( $fivesdrafts as $post )
    {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        ?>
        <h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permalink: <?php the_title(); ?>">
                <?php the_title(); ?>
            </a>
        </h2>
        <?php
    }   
}
else
{
    ?>
    <h2>Not Found</h2>
    <?php
}
?>
```

This code have the same functionality as we use have posts query.